# GIT commit from memory, not file

Tags: git, memory

Is it possible to commit an object directly from memory to a repository, or do you always have to write memory to a file, only to have git reload the file to memory?

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes any sense.  The git repository *is* a bunch of files.

Comment: How are you testing your changes without writing them to a file first? I suppose your compiler or interpreter uses your in-memory changes? Now if you create a ramdisk then you could commit from memory, but you'll still be saving from memory to memory and reloading to memory. Ramdisks also have the cool ability to instantly roll back any commits (and non-committed changes) you haven't pushed, so that feature could be useful too.

Comment: Are you asking if a file needs to be saved (written to disk) before committing?

Comment: There are two cases where I see a use for it:I'd like to explore using git to manage plain-text data records, so I don't need to do tests on code.

Comment: I know the git repository is a bunch of files - but why must the data extracted from those files go through an intermediate stage on disk? There are few cases where I see a use for commit from memory: A) to use git in a collaborative editing environment, where multiple users are editing the same file. B) using git to manage changes to a plain-text data file (which doesn't need to be tested), but changes frequently enough that I don't want to go through the disk each time C) preserve undo capability on a text file that persists between edits of the file & augment the editor's undo capability.

Comment: elaborate the question please. It seems like a good one to me, although the reason you are giving don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you don’t need to write to disk first. You can create blobs from memory, by passing the data to `git hash-object -w --stdin`. You can add those directly to the index or built trees with them and commit directly. Some details can be found here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: Thanks for the reference - it wasn't clear from the non-"plumbing" sections how this could be done. I think that's just what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that this dodges the question a bit -- adding the file to the index also writes the contents to a file on the filesystem until commit (or something else that acts on the index) is invoked.

Comment: @NevikRehnel: That’s not true. Creating an object for the file is part of the commit process. If you hash your blobs, then build a tree and then create a commit object, you are only “commiting”. There are file writes of course. But that is only a result of the git repo beeing stored on a file system. We are still “commit[ing] an object directly from memory to a repository”.

Comment: Oh yes, I overlooked that, sorry. I forgot that the index is only a prepared tree for objects ;)